# I'm trying to get IP address value printed into 4 box's on some Html web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have string with "." in the address trying  to use and Java script with String Tokenizer and slip each address into each box

Source C file which passes the values when requested by the html page (ipcfg/ipcfg_get)

```
/*
* { "ipv4": {
*  "addr": "192.168.1.1",
*  "mask": "255.255.255.0",
*  "gw": "192.168.1.1" }
* }
*/
cp = s;
cp += sprintf(cp, "{ \"ipv4\": {");
cp += sprintf(cp, "\"addr\": \"%d.%d.%d.%d\",",
        IP4_ADDR1(ipv4_addr), IP4_ADDR2(ipv4_addr),
        IP4_ADDR3(ipv4_addr), IP4_ADDR4(ipv4_addr));
cp += sprintf(cp, "\"mask\": \"%d.%d.%d.%d\",",
        IP4_ADDR1(ipv4_mask), IP4_ADDR2(ipv4_mask),
        IP4_ADDR3(ipv4_mask), IP4_ADDR4(ipv4_mask));
cp += sprintf(cp, "\"gw\": \"%d.%d.%d.%d\"",
        IP4_ADDR1(gw_addr), IP4_ADDR2(gw_addr),
        IP4_ADDR3(gw_addr), IP4_ADDR4(gw_addr));
cp += sprintf(cp, "}}");
```

HTML Program to get the values from the C file calling the function and no its not brackets or closing arguments.

```
<script>      
function ipcfg_get () 
{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ipcfg/ipcfg_get.cgi',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var s = 'addr: ' + data.ipv4.addr;
                s += ', mask: '+ data.ipv4.mask;
                s += ', gw: ' + data.ipv4.gw;
            },
       });
}

$(function() {
    $('#btnreset').on('click', ipcfg_get);
$('#btnapply').on('click', ipcfg_set);
});
</script>
```

Comment: where do you want to print?

Comment: you should at least try and define ipcfg_set to show that you have tried something yourself...much more likely to get an answer instead of downvotes.

Comment: The top file is the ipcfg.c     

which contains this definition

int ipcfg_get_cgi(struct httpctl * http)

Answer (score 0):

In your success function do this instead of doing string operations on s.
(J S O N after all stands for JavaScriptObjectNotation so treat the variables as js objects and you shall be fine.)

`var s={};`
 `s.addr=data.ipv4.addr;`
`s.mask=data.ipv4.mask;`
 `s.gw=data.ipv4.gw;`
`//do something with s after this like put it into some div`
`alert(s);`

Comment: I wan to be able to output each address (addr, mask, gw) on separate html text inputs. Like with ip address

Comment: <table class="formgrid">
    <tr><th>IP Address:</th><td><input type="text" name="a1" id="ip1" size="3" value="0">.
    <input type="text" name="a2" size="3" id="ip2" value="0">.
    <input type="text" name="a3" size="3" id="ip3" value="0">.
    <input type="text" name="a4" size="3" id="ip4" value="0"></td></tr>

Comment: Not very clear what you require,but i guess you could do something like this for each ip:
`$('#ip1').val(s.addr);  $('#ip2').val(s.mask);  $('#ip3').val(s.gw);`

Comment: N.B. If you want to split each ip then you could do something like `var splittedAddr=s.addr.toString().split('.');` and then can access each element of that array as `splittedAddr[0],splittedAddr[1]..`